# derivation of the connection between Riemann zeta and primes from Edwards

Tags: number-theory

I am having trouble with this derivation from Edward's Riemann zeta function book:
[image]

The problem is I do not see how he uses the $\log(1-x)$ series in $(1)$ and the steps to get to the summation version.

Comment: $\log\zeta(s)=-\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s})$. Then, for each $p$, substitute $x=p^{-s}$ in the power series for $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews okay but how in this step does the product series become a summation? I mean is it because log makes product become sum from the simple properties of log and how does this go to the final form Edward's shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\log(\zeta(s)) &= \log \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}  \\
    &= \sum_p \log \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}  &&\text{log of product is sum of logs}  \\
    &= \sum_p - \log (1-p^{-s})  &&\text{log exponent rule}  \\
    &= \sum_p - \left( -p^{-s} - \frac{1}{2} (p^{-s})^2 - \frac{1}{3} (p^{-s})^3 - \cdots \right)  &&\text{given $\log$ series}  \\
   &= \sum_p \left( p^{-s} + \frac{1}{2} (p^{-s})^2 + \frac{1}{3} (p^{-s})^3 + \cdots \right)  &&\text{distribute}  \\
    &= \sum_p  \sum_n  \frac{1}{n} p^{-ns}  &&\text{equivalent notation}
\end{align*}

Comment: okay that's sorted out thank you.